# Как удалить ссылку из текста в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь удалить ссылки, используя регулярные выражения. Проблема в том, что моя регулярка отрезает не только ссылку, но и беспробельную часть после неё (которую я хочу оставить).

Регулярное выражение:

```py
re.sub(r"http://\S+|https://\S+", "", text)
```

Пример:

```py
"https://vk.com/wall505680146_2821,id505680146,социальные сети"
" сети,
```

Comment: Почему решили использовать регулярные выражения? На первый взгляд у Вас [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/795/339283).

Comment: Что должно остаться-то?

Comment: должно остаться социальные сети

Comment: решил использовать регулярные т.к. это единственное, что мне знакомо в python для обработки текста

Comment: @Raarity У Вас строка явно разделена на 3 группы с помощью запятой. Так будет всегда? Если да, то можно воспользоваться методом [`split(',')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: Текущее выполнение можно упростить до "http(s)?://\S+"

Comment: @Raarity Подождите, у Вас 2 строки?

Comment: у меня текст в котором есть ссылкки разного формата. В примере я показал, как сработала моя регулярка. Т.е. она удалила ссылку, id , ", социальные "

Comment: `\S` - любой непробельный символ, эквивалент `[^\r\n\t\f\v ]`, как видно запятая и любые другие символы будут попадать под захват регулярным выражением, `[^\s,"`перечислить все символы которые не могут встретится в url`]` - поможет исправить сложившуюся проблему

Comment: @unsetName мне это помогло!

Comment: Я уже увидел, что вам дали аналогичный ответ, если ответ от автора вам помог, то отметьте его как верный, нажав слева от него "галочку", это благодарность за труд отвечающего.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте

```py
import re
s = "https://vk.com/wall505680146_2821,id505680146,социальные сети"
print( re.sub(r"https?://[^,\s]+,?", "", s) )
# => id505680146,социальные сети
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/Q18tQg) и [регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/N23KK5/1).

`https?://[^,\s]+,?` находит

- `https?://` - `http://` или `https://`
- `[^,\s]+` - один и более символов, отличных от пробельных символов и запятой
- `,?` - необязательная запятая.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Регулярки тут не нужны:

```
url = "https://vk.com/wall505680146_2821,id505680146,социальные сети"
print(url.split(',')[-1])
```